# How to find .tpl file of navbar

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I am struggling to find the file of my prestashop page navigation bar.

[Code snippet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmX8W.png)

I need to delete the title tag and after two hours of searching i failed. anybody have any ideas ?

**EDIT**

To clarify it: I need to remove the span title appearing after hovering category on my side navigation block on homepage. Picture:
[Side nav block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joBSv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the navigation bar in the `breadcrumb.tpl` of your installed template.

For the default theme:
`prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/breadcrumb.tpl`

Looking your code that isn't the breadcrumb but the blockcategories module.
So you have to edit this file `category-tree-branch.tpl` that is in this location (if there isn't the override):
`prestashop/modules/blockcategories`

Otherwise (if there is the override):
`prestashop/themes/yourtheme/modules/blockcategories`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for a fast reply. well it didn't helped. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure sarcom is right about it being `category-tree-branch.tpl` - try searching for all occurences of the file in your codebase and chaging each one selectively and seeing if the file in question was the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the `root/themes/your_current_themes` folder.

or

Please find the `root/modules/` folder. May be you can find this.

You can use any search tools: such as grepwin or any others.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but i have already tried this. I literally scanned my whole ftp server and couldn find a solution. 
P.S.: I'm begginer at programming. sorry.